# Installing memcached in Ubuntu server 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memcached

I just installed Linux Ubuntu on a virtual machine and need to install memcached on it. I tried

```
apt-get install memcached
```

but it installs version 1.2.2 (from local repository), which is old. I need to install v 1.4.1 but how do I download it to the Linux box from a command line? I know there should be a way but I am not too good with linux...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you,
Andrey

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the `memcached` web page; copy the download link;  then in a terminal,

```
wget http://memcached.googlecode.com/files/memcached-1.4.1.tar.gz
tar xzf memcached-1.4.1.tar.gz
cd memcached-1.4.1
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Those are generally the basic steps you do when installing Linux software manually, and it doesn't look like `memcached` is any different.

I'm voting to move to ServerFault since that's where this question belongs anyway, but it's a slow night here and I figured I'd answer here so you get the answer possibly a little more quickly.

Answer (score 3):

To install version 1.4.1, follow the instructions of [How can I install memcached?](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_install_memcached?) from the memcached FAQ (sometimes, official FAQ are helpful...):

> For a tutorial, go to:
>   http://blog.ajohnstone.com/archives/installing-memcached
>   Also consider checking your
>   distribution's package management
>   system (apt, yum, etc).
>
> Generic install instructions are
>   standard. memcached requires
>   [libevent](http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) to be installed first.
>   This is most likely available via your
>   distribution's package manager.
>
> If your distribution doesn't have
>   memcached or an updated enough
>   version, installing from source is
>   simple. Fetch the tarball from our
>   [download page](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/downloads/list).
>
> ```
>     $ tar -zxvf memcached-1.x.x.tar.gz
>     $ ./configure
>     $ make
>     $ make test
>     $ sudo make install
> ```
>
> use './configure --help' to see all of
>   the options.

To download the tarball, use `wget`:

```
    $ wget http://memcached.googlecode.com/files/memcached-1.4.1.tar.gz
```